# What is the purpose of using common webdriver object across a complete test

Tags: selenium, webdriver

We pass the same driver object to all page constructors when navigating the page by page in a flow.What are the advantages ,disadvantages and purpose of using this way?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing more than speed. No point wasting time with the overhead of starting a browser each time if the tests can share one. The problem becomes ensuring each test is correctly fulfilling it's responsibility to starting with a clean slate and tearing down the data it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webdriver instance is linked to particular instance of browser which is launched by the corresponding driver object. The same instance needs to be passed to page object constructor in order to keep the test cases running in a single instance of browser(same browser window), which is ideally the case. A new driver instance is only required when next test script starts execution. TestNG framework provides set of annotation where one can control the opening and closing of the browser instances.

Answer (score 1):

A new driver instance requires a new browser session, which might take several seconds to load. If the application you're testing requires a login, you might be waiting another few seconds for that. Suppose you're running a suite of 100 tests on your machine: if you wait 10 seconds for each new browser to load and log in, that's over 16 minutes you'll spend waiting; if you run the same suite on another browser, you're up to 32 minutes of waiting. That time lost can become a workflow problem.

There are two ways to fix this sort of problem.

The more affordable solution is to recycle one browser instance across some or all of your tests. Instead of waiting 10 seconds per browser, per test, you wait 10 seconds per browser and do your best to reset that browser's state between tests.

The more correct solution is to keep your tests isolated from each other and run them in a cloud of (probably virtualized) testing machines. All of the tests can be run in parallel, saving on wall-clock time. Tests don't need to worry about resetting state, because no state is carried between tests. It's easier to ensure complete coverage, because running the suite on another browser is as simple as spinning up some more test machines. This solution requires more computer time, but less wall-clock time because the work is achieved in parallel.

If you're just starting out, the affordable solution is probably more appealing because it's a lot easier to put together.